# Length of the axis in subplot is the same as that of the number of samples in linspace

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two curves in a subplot. the curves are x and x**2.
Here is the code i wrote:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.figsize=[10,10]

x=np.linspace(0,10,50)
x1=np.linspace(0,1.0,num=50)

axes[0,0].plot(x,2*x**2+3,"--r")
axes[0,1].plot(x1,x1**2,x1)
```

this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwQUU.png).
When i plot a single line, the axis is taken according to the linspace and between 0-1, but as soon as i add the other, the x axis jumps to 50. how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the line:

`axes[0,1].plot(x1,x1**2,x1)`

It shall read:

`axes[0,1].plot(x1,x1**2,x1, x1)` to accomplish what you want to do I believe.

Read here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html

- The third way is to specify multiple sets of [x], y, [fmt] groups:

  `plot(x1, y1, 'g^', x2, y2, 'g-')`  <--- you were missing the `y2` from there.